# Не подгружаются картинки при ssr (react + express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ssr

Использую express, чтобы рендерить приложение (create react app) на сервере. Все по стандарту, беру файл index.html из build, засовываю рендер в div#root, приложение приходит, скрипты и стили подключаются, а все картинки выдают 404 (пути из скриптов не соответствуют реальным путям к картинкам). Если полистать страницы, то картинки отрендеренных компонент подгружаются. Без ssr все работает нормально. Конфиг вебпака не трогал. В серверной части не особо понимаю, поэтому взял из интернета :

```
require('ignore-styles')
require('@babel/register')({
ignore: [/(node_module)/],
presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
})
require('./server')
```

Далее код самого рендера:

```
    import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from "../../src/App";
import {reducers} from '../../src/redux/redux';

export const handleRender = (req, res) => {
    const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
    // Render the component to a string
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
            <App />
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  
    // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
    const preloadedState = store.getState();
  
    // Send the rendered page back to the client
    res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
}
  
const renderFullPage = (html, preloadedState) => {
    let indexHTML = fs.readFileSync( path.resolve( __dirname, '../../build/index.html' ), {
      encoding: 'utf8',
    });
    indexHTML = indexHTML.replace('__APP__', html).replace('__STATE__', `globalThis.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(
      /</g,
      '\\u003c'
    )}`);
    return indexHTML;        
}
```

Вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/alexandertonkonog/ssr (код приложения вырезан). Я новичок в работе с ssr и express. Подскажите, куда копать.

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))` я думаю должен быть перед всеми роутами, в данном случае после `const app = express();`

Comment: Или я так понимаю в dist папке нет картинок тех получается? Если да, то нужно еще добавить pablic папку как статическую.

Comment: Если добавить use static до роутов, то возвращает index.html без серверного рендеринга, картинки в папке build media есть, они открываются по своему адресу, но приложение при ssr запрашивает другие адреса, будто они формируются неправильно